# Treatment for catarrh?

Tags: treatment, home-remedy, mucus-phlegm, catarrh, nasal-cavity

I've been having catarrh for 3 days now and it's really becoming hard to bare, till today I've not slept for 3 days because it has totally blocked my nostrils. Is there any home remedy for catarrh.